# how to solve Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, bearer-token

I am try to make jwt authentiation api with beared and i while i am running i get this error and io know how to solve it. Before i add jwt auth this project work without any error .after i added the jwt authentication i get this error .Any one know how to solve this ?I try to find out the problem on debug mode  and i couldn't  because i am new to spring boot .

Console

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.5)

2022-03-25 15:38:03.677  INFO 10892 --- [           main] c.c.jwtsecurity.JwtSecurityApplication   : Starting JwtSecurityApplication using Java 17.0.1 on DESKTOP-VKEIQMG with PID 10892 (C:\Users\chana\IdeaProjects\jwtSecurity\target\classes started by chana in C:\Users\chana\IdeaProjects\jwtSecurity)
2022-03-25 15:38:03.681  INFO 10892 --- [           main] c.c.jwtsecurity.JwtSecurityApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-03-25 15:38:05.182  INFO 10892 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-03-25 15:38:05.198  INFO 10892 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-03-25 15:38:05.199  INFO 10892 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.60]
2022-03-25 15:38:05.422  INFO 10892 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-03-25 15:38:05.423  INFO 10892 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1658 ms
2022-03-25 15:38:05.692  WARN 10892 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configure' defined in class path resource [com/chanaka/jwtsecurity/SecurityConfigurer.class]: Invalid factory method 'configure' on class [com.chanaka.jwtsecurity.SecurityConfigurer]: needs to have a non-void return type!
2022-03-25 15:38:05.701  INFO 10892 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-03-25 15:38:05.719  INFO 10892 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-25 15:38:05.781 ERROR 10892 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configure' defined in class path resource [com/chanaka/jwtsecurity/SecurityConfigurer.class]: Invalid factory method 'configure' on class [com.chanaka.jwtsecurity.SecurityConfigurer]: needs to have a non-void return type!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.chanaka.jwtsecurity.JwtSecurityApplication.main(JwtSecurityApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configure' defined in class path resource [com/chanaka/jwtsecurity/SecurityConfigurer.class]: Invalid factory method 'configure' on class [com.chanaka.jwtsecurity.SecurityConfigurer]: needs to have a non-void return type!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configure' defined in class path resource [com/chanaka/jwtsecurity/SecurityConfigurer.class]: Invalid factory method 'configure' on class [com.chanaka.jwtsecurity.SecurityConfigurer]: needs to have a non-void return type!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:623) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at com.chanaka.jwtsecurity.SecurityConfigurer$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c62e1106.configure(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:264) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:204) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:315) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:93) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at com.chanaka.jwtsecurity.SecurityConfigurer$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c62e1106.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

1

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authentication").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws  Exception {
        return  super.authenticationManagerBean();
   }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

2

```
@Service
public class JwtUtil {
    private  String SECRET_KEY = "secret";

    private  Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    //first
    private <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims,T> claimsResolver) {
        final  Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return  claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }
    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration );
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before( new Date());
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,SECRET_KEY).compact();
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return  createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    public  Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final  String username = extractUsername(token);
        return  (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }

}
```

3

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new User("user","user12", new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

4

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authorizationHeader  = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwt = null ;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);

        }

        if( username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if(jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                                null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource()
                                .buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

5

```
@RestController
public class helloResource {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @GetMapping("/apicall")
    private  String hey(){
     return "hey it succes";
    }
    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationTOken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception{


        try{
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(),authenticationRequest.getPassword())
            );
        }catch (BadCredentialsException e){
            throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password", e);
        }

        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
                .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        final  String jwt = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return  ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));
    }


}
```

Comment: Remove  @Bean from method that returns void (protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)).

Comment: i did it . but it doesn't work

Comment: What is the error now?

Comment: after i remove it i get this error Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-27 08:37:02.628 ERROR 2264 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource

Comment: now i get this error Unable to load class named [io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder] from the thread context, current, or system/application ClassLoaders.  All heuristics have been exhausted.  Class could not be found.  Have you remembered to include the jjwt-impl.jar in your runtime classpath?